# Everything disappears when I frame select anything

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I started watching Blender tutorials and one thing that I noticed on everyone of them is that when they frame select an object (using <kbd>Numpad .</kbd>) they focus and orbit the object and can see the surrounding ones (like the camera and light) but when I do it everything else just disappears no matter the distance. I attached a comparison for you to see.

[image: Screenshot before pressing numpad ., I can see everything]

[image: Screenshot after frame selecting. I can only see the selected object]

Comment: Hello and welcome, you probably have some shortcuts messed up, try to load factory settings (File > defaults > Load factory settings) Then try to toggle local View using Numbpad forward slash (/) or by going to View > Local view

Comment: The behaviour you illustrate (thank you) is the default key-mapping of Shift-H,Hide Unselected.. so it does look like a  personal re-map.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press slash <kbd>/</kbd>
or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: I can confirm focusing and defocusing on the object using "slash" ( / ) toggles the appearance of other objects in the scene (including lights and camera) but I can't tell what slash ( / ) actually does (can't find it in the keymap). If you are able, could you edit your answer and elaborate on the difference between focusing on an object using Slash ( / ) vs Numpad Period ( . )?

Comment: Numpad Period ('.') simply zooms in on the selected object whereas forward slash ('/') takes you into Local view where the selected object **only** is visible. You will also see 'Local' in the top left corner of the 3D view if you're in Local view.